# Monero and Tor onion service

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, tor

Is it possible to run Monero completely over and as a Tor onion service?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are two guides:

1. https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/tor_wallet.html and
2. https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor